# Difference between SRC and BIN?

Tags: java, eclipse

What is the difference between the `src` folder and the `bin` folder in an Eclipse project? They both seem the same, however, `src` uses .java files whereas `bin` uses .class files. Why is this? What difference do they have?

Comment: .java files go in /src, of course.  I usually put execution scripts (e.g. *.bat or *.cmd for Windows, *.sh for *nix) in /bin.

Comment: To reinforce, the source goes in /src, of course, of course

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`src` files are your raw, human-readable source code (in this case, `.java`).
`bin` files are your compiled code (in this case, `.class`)

Answer (score 3):

if you are working on a Java project, src folder and its subfolders would hold the .java files (human readable codes). "Bin" folder is usually where the compiled files are copied to (computer readable codes). For example, this folder will have the .class, .jar etc files which are compiled.